# In theory how would one use stacks for mergesort in C?

Tags: c, mergesort

I was thinking of generating all the indexes that would be needed for the merge function in mergesort and I tried it out but it didn't work out well as I would get indexes that negative and therefore it made the program crash.

Here is the code:

```
void myMergesort(void **A, int n, int(cmp)(void *, void*)) {
    Stack *s;
    s = stack_new();
    int i, j;
    int l = 0, h = n - 1;
    int m = (l + h) / 2;
    stack_push(s, (void *)l);
    stack_push(s, (void *)h);
    for (i = h; i > 0; i = i / 2) {
        for (j = 0; j <= h ; j = j + i) {
            stack_push(s, (void *)j);
        }
        if (j > h  && j - i != h) {
            stack_push(s, (void *)j);
        }
    }
    while (stack_isEmpty(s)==0) {
        h = (int)stack_pop(s);
        l = (int)stack_pop(s);
        m = (l + h) / 2;
        if (l < h) {
            merge(A, l, m, h, cmp);
        }   
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I am going in the right direction and if I'm not can someone push me in the right direction?